# i have a table which contains more than 50 rows. i want to retrive the rows based on starting and ending count which is provided in jsp using struts

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2

```
   <s:textfield label="from" name="from"/>
   <s:textfield label="to" name="to"/>
   <s:submit value="Get List" action="getlist"/>
```

when i enter values in "from" field and "to" field then it should get all the values from starting count to ending count and display in jsp page.

```
    <table><tr>USER ID</tr> 
       <tr>USER NAME</tr> 
        <tr>USER ADDRESS</tr> 

     <s:iterate value="datalist"/>
    <td> <s:property value="%{userid}"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="%{username}"/</td>
     <td><s:property value="%{useraddress}"/></td>
      </table>
```

what should be the hibernate query to perform this action

Comment: Show what you have got so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your query with the `Session.createQuery()` method (you can use also the `createCriteria()` or `createSQLQuery()` methods, the methods to use to limit the rows to a subset are the same).

Then use the `setFirstResult(from)` and `setMaxResult(max)` methods of the `Query` class (you'll have to calculate the `max` value thanks to `from` and `to` values, something like `max = to - from`). You'll limit the `ResultSet` to `max` rows from the `from` value.

Then execute the query with `Query.list()` method.